# Spring and WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to implement a Dashboard where some users (those who have the role of Manager) can add, update and remove other users. Is there a way to add a new user updating not only my database but also the wso2 identity server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For USER CRUD operations you can use the SCIM User APIs mentioned in [this doc](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint).

You can create a new role in the identity server and add the following permissions to it. Adding these permissions will make sure that the created role has only user view, update and delete permissions.

```
 - /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/view
 - /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/create
 - /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/update
 - /permission/admin/manage/identity/usermgt/delete
```

[image]

After creating the role, you can assign the role to the user who wants to manage users. Once done you can get a token for that user and use that token to authenticate the SCIM User APIs mentioned in [this doc](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint) and manage users.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was searching for! But I have a problem, if I call the API (for example POST localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users) from Postman and I use Basic Authorization (username and password) it works, but if I use OAuth2.0 inserting the JWT token, the Auth URL (localhost:9443/oauth/authorize), the access token URL (localhost:9443/oauth/token), the client-id, the client-secret and scope (internal_user_mgt_create) it doesn't work, I get a 403 Forbidden even though I gave the user the permissions you wrote me

Comment: Can you share a sample curl that you use? Make sure to mask any sensitive information

Comment: curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <client-id:client-secret>" -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=internal_user_mgt_create" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

Comment: Try this.
curl -L -X POST 'https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/oauth2/token' -H 'Authorization: Basic aWNuZk1RQ0lGdlBwVjR0d3lscW5UT0JhcXFZYTo4MWVSNldLcHZUWDhFbjNiS3hvUUdGX0NwQmdh' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'username=manager' --data-urlencode 'password=manager' --data-urlencode 'scope=internal_user_mgt_list'

Comment: Use the above to get the token and change the scopes accordingly, If you are trying with the latest IS (IS 6.0.0) make sure to mark the application as a `management application` and then try the token call.

Answer (score 2):

For user related CRUD operations (creation, read, update and delete), in wso2 identity server you can use **SCIM2.0 /Users API** https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/

So you can call relevant SCIM2.0 API related to your operation from your dashboard to add, update, delete users in wso2 identity server.

- For Add new user : Use **POST** request to **/Users** endpoint. (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/createUser)
- For Update a user : Use **PUT** request(https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/updateUser) or **PATCH** request(https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/patchUser) to **/Users/{user-id}** endpoint.
- For Delete a user : Use **DELETE** request(https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/deleteUser) to **/Users/{user-id}** endpoint.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was searching for! But I have a problem, if I call the API (for example POST localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users) from Postman and I use Basic Authorization (username and password) it works, but if I use OAuth2.0 inserting the JWT token, the Auth URL (localhost:9443/oauth/authorize), the access token URL (localhost:9443/oauth/token), the client-id, the client-secret and scope (internal_user_mgt_create) it doesn't work, I get a 403 Forbidden even though I gave the user the permissions you wrote me

Comment: What is the WSO2 identity server version you are using?

Comment: Did you register your application as a management application? In WSO2 identity server 6.0.0, if you need to access the management APIs, you need to create the service provider as a "Management Application". Refer [1] for more information.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/applications/register-sp/#register-a-service-provider